# photoshopCCV19linux installation problem

Tags: linux, windows, bash, debian, kali-linux

хочу установить photoshop на kali. следую инструкциям [Gictorbit/photoshopCClinux](https://github.com/Gictorbit/photoshopCClinux). стартует и вылет. [image: сообщение wine при вылете]

залез в логи в ~/.photoshopCCV19
**setuplog.log**:

```
Mon Oct 10 06:36:33 PM CEST 2022 : ================| script executed |================
Mon Oct 10 06:36:33 PM CEST 2022 : is64 checked...
Mon Oct 10 06:36:33 PM CEST 2022 : package[1;36m wine[0m is installed...
Mon Oct 10 06:36:33 PM CEST 2022 : package[1;36m wine64[0m is installed...
Mon Oct 10 06:36:33 PM CEST 2022 : package[1;36m md5sum[0m is installed...
Mon Oct 10 06:36:33 PM CEST 2022 : package[1;36m winetricks[0m is installed...
Mon Oct 10 06:36:33 PM CEST 2022 : create[0;36m /home/greenowl/.photoshopCCV19/prefix[0m directory...
Mon Oct 10 06:36:33 PM CEST 2022 : wine variables exported...
Mon Oct 10 06:36:40 PM CEST 2022 : prefix configured...
Mon Oct 10 06:36:50 PM CEST 2022 : set dark mode for wine...
Mon Oct 10 06:36:50 PM CEST 2022 : create[0;36m /home/greenowl/.photoshopCCV19/resources[0m directory...
Mon Oct 10 06:37:43 PM CEST 2022 : md5 is not match
Mon Oct 10 06:37:43 PM CEST 2022 : downloading photoshopCC-V19.1.6-2018x64.tgz ...
Mon Oct 10 06:37:43 PM CEST 2022 : using aria2c to download photoshopCC-V19.1.6-2018x64.tgz
Mon Oct 10 06:37:43 PM CEST 2022 : downloading photoshopCC-V19.1.6-2018x64.tgz ...
Mon Oct 10 06:37:43 PM CEST 2022 : using aria2c to download photoshopCC-V19.1.6-2018x64.tgz
Mon Oct 10 06:37:43 PM CEST 2022 : downloading photoshopCC-V19.1.6-2018x64.tgz ...
Mon Oct 10 06:37:43 PM CEST 2022 : using aria2c to download photoshopCC-V19.1.6-2018x64.tgz
Mon Oct 10 06:37:43 PM CEST 2022 : sorry something went wrong during download photoshopCC-V19.1.6-2018x64.tgz
Mon Oct 10 06:42:15 PM CEST 2022 : ================| script executed |================
Mon Oct 10 06:42:15 PM CEST 2022 : is64 checked...
Mon Oct 10 06:42:15 PM CEST 2022 : package[1;36m wine[0m is installed...
Mon Oct 10 06:42:15 PM CEST 2022 : package[1;36m wine64[0m is installed...
Mon Oct 10 06:42:15 PM CEST 2022 : package[1;36m md5sum[0m is installed...
Mon Oct 10 06:42:15 PM CEST 2022 : package[1;36m winetricks[0m is installed...
Mon Oct 10 06:42:15 PM CEST 2022 : [0;36m/home/greenowl/.photoshopCCV19/prefix[0m directory exists deleting it...
Mon Oct 10 06:42:15 PM CEST 2022 : create[0;36m /home/greenowl/.photoshopCCV19/prefix[0m directory...
Mon Oct 10 06:42:15 PM CEST 2022 : wine variables exported...
Mon Oct 10 06:42:22 PM CEST 2022 : prefix configured...
Mon Oct 10 06:42:32 PM CEST 2022 : set dark mode for wine...
Mon Oct 10 06:42:32 PM CEST 2022 : [0;36m/home/greenowl/.photoshopCCV19/resources[0m directory exists deleting it...
Mon Oct 10 06:42:32 PM CEST 2022 : create[0;36m /home/greenowl/.photoshopCCV19/resources[0m directory...
Mon Oct 10 06:43:22 PM CEST 2022 : downloading photoshopCC-V19.1.6-2018x64.tgz ...
Mon Oct 10 06:43:22 PM CEST 2022 : using aria2c to download photoshopCC-V19.1.6-2018x64.tgz
Mon Oct 10 06:43:25 PM CEST 2022 : [1;36mphotoshopCC-V19.1.6-2018x64.tgz[0m detected
Mon Oct 10 06:43:25 PM CEST 2022 : extract photoshop...
Mon Oct 10 06:43:29 PM CEST 2022 : install photoshop...
Mon Oct 10 06:43:29 PM CEST 2022 : [1;33mPlease don't change default Destination Folder[0m
Mon Oct 10 06:45:03 PM CEST 2022 : removing useless helper.exe plugin to avoid errors
Mon Oct 10 06:45:03 PM CEST 2022 : photoshopCC V19 x64 installed...
Mon Oct 10 06:45:08 PM CEST 2022 : downloading replacement.tgz ...
Mon Oct 10 06:45:08 PM CEST 2022 : using aria2c to download replacement.tgz
Mon Oct 10 07:02:00 PM CEST 2022 : [1;36mreplacement.tgz[0m detected
Mon Oct 10 07:02:00 PM CEST 2022 : extract replacement component...
Mon Oct 10 07:02:00 PM CEST 2022 : replace component compeleted...
Mon Oct 10 07:02:00 PM CEST 2022 : deleting resources folder
Mon Oct 10 07:02:00 PM CEST 2022 : create[0;36m /home/greenowl/.photoshopCCV19/launcher[0m directory...
Mon Oct 10 07:02:00 PM CEST 2022 : launcher.sh detected...
Mon Oct 10 07:02:00 PM CEST 2022 : desktop entry detected...
Mon Oct 10 07:02:00 PM CEST 2022 : create photoshop command...
Mon Oct 10 07:05:44 PM CEST 2022 : [1;33mwhen you run photoshop for the first time it may take a while[0m
Mon Oct 10 07:05:44 PM CEST 2022 : Almost finished...
```

**wine-error.log**:

```
0048:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hr 0x80004002
0048:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, hr 0x80004002
0048:err:ole:apartment_get_local_server_stream Failed: 0x80004002
0048:err:ole:start_rpcss Failed to open RpcSs service
0050:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hr 0x80004002
0050:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, hr 0x80004002
0050:err:ole:apartment_get_local_server_stream Failed: 0x80004002
wine: configuration in L"/home/greenowl/.photoshopCCV19/prefix" has been updated.
===============| photoshop CC v19 |===============
00cc:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0x6bbc38, 1): stub
00cc:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0001005A, 006BBC38): stub
00cc:fixme:nls:RtlSetProcessPreferredUILanguages 4, 0067EB78, 00000000
0050:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0x25e540, 0): stub
0050:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0000000000010020, 000000000025E540): stub
00cc:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
00cc:fixme:explorerframe:taskbar_list_SetProgressState iface 006BC820, hwnd 0003004C, flags 1 stub!
00cc:fixme:explorerframe:taskbar_list_SetProgressValue iface 006BC820, hwnd 0003004C, ullCompleted 0, ullTotal 4016870067fbac stub!
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
0130:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0x7988f0, 1): stub
0130:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (00030062, 007988F0): stub
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
0138:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42u.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\users\\greenowl\\PhotoshopSE\\robocopy.exe") not found
0138:err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Importing dlls for L"C:\\users\\greenowl\\PhotoshopSE\\robocopy.exe" failed, status c0000135
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
0140:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42u.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\users\\greenowl\\PhotoshopSE\\robocopy.exe") not found
0140:err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Importing dlls for L"C:\\users\\greenowl\\PhotoshopSE\\robocopy.exe" failed, status c0000135
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
0148:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42u.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\users\\greenowl\\PhotoshopSE\\robocopy.exe") not found
0148:err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Importing dlls for L"C:\\users\\greenowl\\PhotoshopSE\\robocopy.exe" failed, status c0000135
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
0150:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42u.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\users\\greenowl\\PhotoshopSE\\robocopy.exe") not found
0150:err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Importing dlls for L"C:\\users\\greenowl\\PhotoshopSE\\robocopy.exe" failed, status c0000135
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
0158:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42u.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\users\\greenowl\\PhotoshopSE\\robocopy.exe") not found
0158:err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Importing dlls for L"C:\\users\\greenowl\\PhotoshopSE\\robocopy.exe" failed, status c0000135
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
0160:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42u.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\users\\greenowl\\PhotoshopSE\\robocopy.exe") not found
0160:err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Importing dlls for L"C:\\users\\greenowl\\PhotoshopSE\\robocopy.exe" failed, status c0000135
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
0168:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42u.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\users\\greenowl\\PhotoshopSE\\robocopy.exe") not found
0168:err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Importing dlls for L"C:\\users\\greenowl\\PhotoshopSE\\robocopy.exe" failed, status c0000135
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
reg: The operation completed successfully
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100

System error 3 has occurred.

Path not found.

00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
00cc:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
```

ответ в консоли, при попытке запустить приложение:
**~/.photoshopCCV19/launcher# bash launcher.sh**

```
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0000000180000000)
0024:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventSetInformation (deadbeef, 2, 000000004A90F960, 43) stub
0024:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventSetInformation (deadbeef, 2, 0000000001C715A8, 43) stub
0024:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventSetInformation (deadbeef, 2, 0000000001CFD7B8, 43) stub
0024:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventSetInformation (deadbeef, 2, 0000000001D975A8, 43) stub
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0000000001F30000)
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0000000001DC0000)
0024:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation 0000000003E60000 0 000000000011F6E0 4 stub
0024:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation 0000000003F70000 0 000000000011F6E0 4 stub
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0000000002690000)
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0000000002180000)
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0000000003010000)
0024:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000011F410 1 C) semi-stub
0024:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x8 000000000011E4F0 0000000000000000 000000000011E4E8) returning a dummy value (current locale)
0024:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x8 000000000011E4F0 00000000038E4960 000000000011E4E8) returning a dummy value (current locale)
0024:fixme:seh:WerRegisterRuntimeExceptionModule (L"C:\\users\\greenowl\\PhotoshopSE\\dvacrashhandler.dll", 00000000038DD8C0) stub
0024:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000011FC90 1 C) semi-stub
0024:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000011FC90 1 C) semi-stub
0024:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000011FC90 1 C) semi-stub
0024:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000011EF10 1 C) semi-stub
0024:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000011E030 1 C) semi-stub
0024:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000011DD40 1 C) semi-stub
0024:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000011EDE0 1 C) semi-stub
0024:fixme:ntdll:NtSetInformationToken unimplemented class 24
0050:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0x25e540, 0): stub
0050:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0000000000010020, 000000000025E540): stub
0024:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0x5db8d90, 1): stub
0024:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0000000000010C50, 0000000005DB8D90): stub
0120:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000011F820 1 C) semi-stub
0120:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000011F6E0 1 C) semi-stub
0120:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000011F410 1 C) semi-stub
0024:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
0120:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
0120:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000011EFD0 1 C) semi-stub
0120:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000011EFD0 1 C) semi-stub
0120:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000011EE80 1 C) semi-stub
013c:fixme:ole:CoInitializeSecurity 0000000000000000, -1, 0000000000000000, 0000000000000000, 1, 3, 0000000000000000, 0, 0000000000000000 stub
0120:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000011EF50 1 C) semi-stub
0120:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000011E040 1 C) semi-stub
0120:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000011E290 1 C) semi-stub
0120:fixme:wbemprox:client_security_SetBlanket 00000002419C2DA0, 00000000001757E0, 10, 0, (null), 3, 3, 0000000000000000, 0x00000000
0120:fixme:wbemprox:client_security_Release 00000002419C2DA0
0120:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000011E630 1 C) semi-stub
0120:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000011DEE0 1 C) semi-stub
0120:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000011DEE0 1 C) semi-stub
0120:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000011DE60 1 C) semi-stub
0118:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000688F670 1 C) semi-stub
0150:fixme:wia:wiadevmgr_QueryInterface interface {00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} not implemented
0150:fixme:wia:wiadevmgr_QueryInterface interface {00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} not implemented
0150:fixme:wia:wiadevmgr_QueryInterface interface {00000019-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} not implemented
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (00000000086A0000)
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_return_trigger (00000000086A0000)
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0000000008F50000)
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_return_trigger (0000000008F50000)
0024:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (000000000011E0C0 0000000000000000): stub
0024:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation 0000000008E10000 0 000000000011E670 4 stub
0024:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (000000000011E0C0 0000000000000000): stub
0024:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (000000000011E0C0 0000000000000000): stub
0024:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (000000000011E0C0 0000000000000000): stub
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0000000008CF0000)
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_return_trigger (0000000008CF0000)
0024:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation 0000000008720000 0 000000000011E730 4 stub
0024:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (000000000011E0C0 0000000000000000): stub
0024:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (000000000011E0C0 0000000000000000): stub
0024:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (000000000011E0C0 0000000000000000): stub
0024:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation 0000000008BD0000 0 000000000011E670 4 stub
0024:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (000000000011E0C0 0000000000000000): stub
0024:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (000000000011E0C0 0000000000000000): stub
0024:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (000000000011E0C0 0000000000000000): stub
0024:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (000000000011E0C0 0000000000000000): stub
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0000000008A90000)
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0000000008B10000)
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_return_trigger (0000000008B10000)
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_return_trigger (0000000008A90000)
0024:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000011E9A0 1 C) semi-stub
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (000000000A260000)
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (000000000A2A0000)
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (000000006F130000)
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (000000000A2E0000)
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (000000000A360000)
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (000000000A4F0000)
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (000000000BAD0000)
017c:fixme:sync:SetWaitableTimerEx (0000000000000208, 000000000C03FC80, 0, 0000000000000000, 0000000000000000, 0000000000000000, 32) semi-stub
0024:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (000000000011E550 0000000000000000): stub
0024:fixme:wtsapi:WTSRegisterSessionNotification Stub 0000000000010056 0x00000001
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_return_trigger (000000000BAD0000)
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_return_trigger (000000000A4F0000)
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_return_trigger (000000000A360000)
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_return_trigger (000000000A2E0000)
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_return_trigger (000000006F130000)
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_return_trigger (000000000A2A0000)
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_return_trigger (000000000A260000)
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_return_trigger (0000000003010000)
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_return_trigger (0000000002180000)
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_return_trigger (0000000002690000)
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_return_trigger (0000000001DC0000)
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_return_trigger (0000000001F30000)
0024:fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_return_trigger (0000000180000000)
```

как я понял - не хватает MFC42u.DLL для robocopy.exe. но я добавил её в (уже с файлом):

/home/greenowl/.photoshopCCV19/prefix/drive_c/users/greenowl/PhotoshopSE/mfc42u.dll
/home/greenowl/.photoshopCCV19/prefix/drive_c/windows/syswow64/mfc42u.dll
/home/greenowl/.photoshopCCV19/prefix/drive_c/windows/system32/mfc42u.dll

также дублировал под:
/home/greenowl/.photoshopCCV19/prefix/drive_c/users/greenowl/PhotoshopSE/MFC42u.DLL
/home/greenowl/.photoshopCCV19/prefix/drive_c/windows/syswow64/MFC42u.DLL
/home/greenowl/.photoshopCCV19/prefix/drive_c/windows/system32/MFC42u.DLL

думал поможет, но нет - не работает. ошибка осталась. как решить?

Comment: При всём уважении, но фотошоп под линух называется gimp. А если вам нужен действительно именно фотошоп - то устанавливайте его в windows (или mac) - так будет заметно меньше проблем.

Comment: @Sheridan я понимаю, но задача установить именно под Kali Linux.